# Not all installed packages are listed in the Ubuntu Software app

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-center

This is on 16.04 LTS.

My understanding is that Ubuntu Software (formerly the Software Center) should list all installed packages on the system. However, mine doesn't. For example, I've installed Google Chrome, VirtualBox, and Dropbox. Chrome is listed in Ubuntu Software, but the two others aren't.

Why is this? Is it a bug or intended behavior?

Comment: Those 3 packages are most likely installed from third party sources (PPA's or similar) and not via the ubuntu sources - therefor not available in the Software Center.

Comment: @dufte Yes, they were all installed from third party repositories. But that's why I'm scratching my head - why would Google Chrome appear in the Software Center but not the other two programs?

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of packages installed locally do this in your terminal:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall
```

(The -v tag "inverts" grep to return non-matching lines)

To get a list of a specific package installed:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep postgres
```

Alternatively, simply use

```
dpkg -l
```

**Ubuntu 14.04 and above**

```
apt list --installed
```